# Visualize Sparse Input from SKlearn Kmeans with MatplotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

cc_tfid = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(cc_corpus)
cc_km = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 99, n_init = 4, verbose = False )
cc_km.fit(cc_tfid)

plt.scatter(cc_tfid[:, 0], cc_tfid[:, 1])
centroids = cc_km.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=200, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I can visualize the centroids but not the points because they are from a sparse matrix. How do I plot this please?

Comment: Can you share the data for replicating the problem ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/knwsoto5sa8blbg/cc_corpus?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the sparse matrices to dense arrays using `.toarray()`:

```
plt.scatter(cc_tfid[:, 0].toarray(), cc_tfid[:, 1].toarray())
```

Note that projecting all points on the first two dimensions of the TF-IDF vector space is likely to result in quite the useless plot. You would be better off piping the data through PCA or t-SNE to reduce the dimensionality to 2.